# Error running packaged python program using pyqt5 and cryptograpy module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, packaging

So I've written a small program to encrypt some text, using the cryptography module and PyQt5 for some GUI stuff around it. Ive packaged it with pyinstaller and cx_freeze resulting in different errors when trying to launch the app. The standalone program works when I launch it with python.

pyinstaller:

```
jfk422@jfk422-MLinux ~/Desktop/Axon/build/index $ ./index Error loading Python lib '/home/jfk422/Desktop/Axon/build/index/libpython3.6m.so.1.0': /home/jfk422/Desktop/Axon/build/index/libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

cx_freeze:

```
jfk422@jfk422-MLinux ~/Desktop/Axon/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.6 $ ./index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jfk422/Desktop/Axon/create.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

Source code:
https://github.com/JFK422/Axon

Other information:
python 3.6.1
Distro: LinuxMint
Version: 18.1
Kernel: 4.4.0-92-generic

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Assafs The program wont launch. Console log is attached. Realized, the wrong one was in cx_freeze.

Comment: According to the error, did you check to see if the _cffi_backend exists and that your Python padding.py file can see it?

Comment: The cffi module is present, the accessability is also there.